# Cannot install plugin on JIRA Server

Tags: nginx, docker, jira

We have JIRA-Software 7 running on a custom docker machine with a Postgres DB and nginx as a reverse proxy (SSL). The custom domain is https://jira.url.de and is working so far. Installation has not been a problem.

But now i wanted to install a plugin and i get the following error:
`An unexpected error has occurred. Please refer to the logs for more information.`

First of all where can i find the logs?

Second - i found out that if i click on "Manage Add-on i will be directed to  a 500 error on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/plugins/servlet/upm`

I read somewhere about configuring the server.xml file in order to correct the plugin url. But how can i edit this file? I can not find it inside the docker container.

## UPDATE

if i try to update the *Atlassian Universal Plugin Manager Plugin* i get the following console Notice:

`[blocked] The page at https://jira.url.de/plugins/servlet/upm was not allowed to display insecure content from http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/plugins/self-update/1.0/.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by clicking to Manage Add-ons you will go to loopback IP Address, most likely your Base URL is not configured properly. Thus, I would say ensure that your base URL configured properly.

Other than that, you need to ensure that you do have `proxyName` and `proxyPort` configured in `server.xml` file. I would say check this [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/integrating-jira-with-nginx-426115340.html) for full details about Nginx configuration.

Lastly, installing plugin from UPM requires access to Marketplace. Thus, you need to ensure that your docker image is able to communicate with Atlassian Marketplace.

Hint:

Monitor atlassian-jira.log file which is in home directory of the jira. That way, you will get better information from the logs.

Comment: I could finally find the server.xml file and configure the correct nginx Proxy Connector. Thanks for the tip - it is working now!